# Page not found (404) error. "The current path, dashboard/auth/login/, didn’t match any of these."

Tags: apache-2.4, django, openstack, ubuntu-20.04, openstack-horizon

I'm attempting to get Devstack and Horizon working on Ubuntu 20.04.

Devstack seems to install OK. I'm following the steps: [All-In-One Single Machine](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/guides/single-machine.html), [DevStack Networking](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/networking.html), [(Horizon) Quickstart](https://docs.openstack.org/horizon/latest/contributor/quickstart.html), and [OpenStack, Devstack and Horizon... on Medium](https://medium.com/@BethElwell/openstack-devstack-and-horizon-installing-and-setting-up-a-basic-openstack-environment-5ebf14acee21).

Devstack seems OK. And starting Horizon with `tox -e runserver -- 13x.xx.xx.200:9000` doesn't generate any errors in and of itself.

But when I go to 13x.xx.xx.200:9000 from a browser, I get ...
[image: Page not found (404)]

***Install STEPS***

drwxr-xr-x 21 stack stack 4096 Aug 24 09:34 stack

```
# useradd -s /bin/bash -d /opt/stack -m stack
# echo "stack ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" | sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/stack
# su - stack
# git clone https://opendev.org/openstack/devstack
$ cd devstack/
$ find . -iname "local.conf"
$ cp -p ./samples/local.conf .
$ vi local.conf 
  (See /opt/stack/devstack/local.conf below)
$ ./stack.sh 
$ cd ..
$ git clone https://git.openstack.org/openstack/horizon
$ cd ./horizon/openstack_dashboard
$ cd local
  (Did not alter local_settings.py. I let Horizon alter the file at the first tox run. I manually validated later)
$ cd ..
$ tox -e runserver -- 13x.xx.xx.200:9000
```

***/opt/stack/devstack/local.conf***

```
[[local|localrc]]
ADMIN_PASSWORD=xxxredactedxxx
DATABASE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD

PUBLIC_INTERFACE=enp4s0f1

LOGFILE=$DEST/logs/stack.sh.log
LOGDAYS=2

SWIFT_HASH=66axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2000f5
SWIFT_REPLICAS=1
SWIFT_DATA_DIR=$DEST/data

enable_plugin neutron https://opendev.org/openstack/neutron
enable_service q-trunk
enable_service q-qos

[[post-config|$GLANCE_API_CONF]]
[DEFAULT]
default_store=file
```

***/opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/local/local_settings.py***

```
import os

from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from horizon.utils import secret_key
from openstack_dashboard.settings import HORIZON_CONFIG

DEBUG = True
COMPRESS_ENABLED = False # Added by me
LOCAL_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

SECRET_KEY = secret_key.generate_or_read_from_file(
    os.path.join(LOCAL_PATH, '.secret_key_store'))

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"


LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'console': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s'
        },
        'operation': {
            # The format of "%(message)s" is defined by
            # OPERATION_LOG_OPTIONS['format']
            'format': '%(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'null': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.NullHandler',
        },
        'console': {
            # Set the level to "DEBUG" for verbose output logging.
            'level': 'DEBUG' if DEBUG else 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'console',
        },
        'operation': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'operation',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'horizon': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'horizon.operation_log': {
            'handlers': ['operation'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'openstack_dashboard': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'novaclient': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'cinderclient': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'keystoneauth': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'keystoneclient': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'glanceclient': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'neutronclient': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'swiftclient': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'oslo_policy': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'openstack_auth': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django.template': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'requests': {
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'urllib3': {
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'chardet.charsetprober': {
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'iso8601': {
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'scss': {
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}

SECURITY_GROUP_RULES = {
    'all_tcp': {
        'name': _('All TCP'),
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '1',
        'to_port': '65535',
    },
    'all_udp': {
        'name': _('All UDP'),
        'ip_protocol': 'udp',
        'from_port': '1',
        'to_port': '65535',
    },
    'all_icmp': {
        'name': _('All ICMP'),
        'ip_protocol': 'icmp',
        'from_port': '-1',
        'to_port': '-1',
    },
    'ssh': {
        'name': 'SSH',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '22',
        'to_port': '22',
    },
    'smtp': {
        'name': 'SMTP',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '25',
        'to_port': '25',
    },
    'dns': {
        'name': 'DNS',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '53',
        'to_port': '53',
    },
    'http': {
        'name': 'HTTP',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '80',
        'to_port': '80',
    },
    'pop3': {
        'name': 'POP3',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '110',
        'to_port': '110',
    },
    'imap': {
        'name': 'IMAP',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '143',
        'to_port': '143',
    },
    'ldap': {
        'name': 'LDAP',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '389',
        'to_port': '389',
    },
    'https': {
        'name': 'HTTPS',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '443',
        'to_port': '443',
    },
    'smtps': {
        'name': 'SMTPS',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '465',
        'to_port': '465',
    },
    'imaps': {
        'name': 'IMAPS',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '993',
        'to_port': '993',
    },
    'pop3s': {
        'name': 'POP3S',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '995',
        'to_port': '995',
    },
    'ms_sql': {
        'name': 'MS SQL',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '1433',
        'to_port': '1433',
    },
    'mysql': {
        'name': 'MYSQL',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '3306',
        'to_port': '3306',
    },
    'rdp': {
        'name': 'RDP',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '3389',
        'to_port': '3389',
    },
}

WEBROOT = "/dashboard/"
COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True
OPENSTACK_KEYSTONE_DEFAULT_ROLE = "member"
OPENSTACK_HOST = "13x.xx.xx.200"
OPENSTACK_KEYSTONE_URL = "http://13x.xx.xx.200/identity/v3"
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
```